How to specify which Android Activity should be launched after a configuration change?
I have two activities - LaunchActivity and GameActivity. It's necessary for LaunchActivity to open first because it launches GameActivity with configuration parameters. This is working fine except when configuration changes occur.
When a configuration change occurs while GameActivity is active, the OS destroys that activity and re-creates it when resumed. This causes a crash because GameActivity needs configuration data from LaunchActivity.
Is there a way to have Android OS ALWAYS launch my app with LaunchActivity, even after a configuration change?

Your activity needs to support config changes on its own.


It's necessary for LaunchActivity to open first because it launches GameActivity with configuration parameters.

That is a fairly substantial architectural bug, one that you will need to fix. Options include:

Consolidating them into a single activity, perhaps using fragments or composables to represent separate screens

Holding those configuration values in the saved instance state Bundle, or modern wrappers for it (e.g., a ViewModel backed by a SavedStateHandle)

Holding those configuration values someplace outside of any activity, such as in a singleton repository (ideally managed by a dependency inversion framework, such as Dagger/Hilt)

Opt out of automatic configuration changes, via android:configChanges in the manifest, and handle them manually


Since you have the android-ndk tag, my guess is that GameActivity is using some NDK-based game framework. That may make some of these options less enticing. On the flip side, any game framework worth using should have well-documented options for dealing with configuration changes — if the one you chose does not, perhaps you should reconsider that choice. This aspect of Android has been around for 16 years; surely the game framework developers will have had time to abide by it.

Is there a way to have Android OS ALWAYS launch my app with LaunchActivity, even after a configuration change?

No, other than by having just one activity (see first bullet above).

Thanks for the info CommonsWare! I tried android:configChanges in the manifest but it didn't work for several configuration changes, such as changing the system language and changing the system font.

@Bungles: "changing the system language" -- that is locale in the android:configChanges roster. "changing the system font" -- that would be a mix of fontScale and fontWeightAdjustment. However, you should be listing all of them, as otherwise your app will be broken for the ones that you skip. (and yes, it would be really nice if they would have supported * or some such to say "I'm opting out of all of them", but, hey...)

@Bungles: And note that there are some things that behave like configuration changes yet are not. See this and this for more.

Oof. Then this is going to be fun...
